# Ruby on Rails route catch all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes, action

```
 match ':controller(:/action(:/id))', :via => [:get, :post]
```

This may be an old way of doing things, but as I understand it this is the last thing on your routes list as a fail safe.

I get an error stating Missing :action key on routes definition.

This may be my fault for starting of with a beta version of rails (5.beta.3) (ruby 2.3)

Gemfile - in case there is something I am overlooking.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'devise', github: 'twalpole/devise', branch: 'rails5'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
gem "passenger", ">= 5.0.25", require: "phusion_passenger/rack_handler"


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '>= 5.0.0.beta3', '< 5.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.x'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem "annotate"
  gem "better_errors"

end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colon needs to be on the other side of the slash:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]
```